# How to "overwrite" many columns base on column name without new columns being generated?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, merge, overwrite

I'm calculating weekly detection sex ratios by year for a study species across different sites. The goal is to create a set of tables (different tables for each site) with the row names as year and col names as week number.

As it currently stands, when using a loop to generate capture tables by sex, not all sexes were detected at each site every week, so instead of generating a column with NAs it just doesn't create a column for that week, so when I attempt to create a new table by division it doesn't work due to unequal dimensions of the male and female tables.

I've generated a 'dummy table' that is the correct dimensions with the correct labels for weeks and years, populated with NAs, but I don't know how to take a another table and overwrite only those columns which have the same name so that the NA columns are preserved as placeholders. Every join, anitjoin, bind list, or merge I've tried returns the two tables combined with new column names and all values present.

I've tried by first subsetting the data by sex and then site, as the plan is for each site to get its own table. Then aggregating the data such that the columns are week, year, and count (the number detected of that sex at that site, that week of that year). After that it gets cast/dcast to show the years as rows and weeks as columns.

I'm not sure how to maintain the same dimensions and column names for all data frames, which is I think necessary to create a table of the male:female ratio.

```
dat_male <- subset(dat, dat$Sex == "1")
dat_fem <- subset(dat, dat$Sex == "2")
```

The main data table has a separate line for every time a specimen was detected, so I subset out the sexes

```
df1<-as.data.frame(lapply(dat_week_total_table, function(x) rep.int(NA, length(x)))) #data frame with NAs of correct dimensions and col names.

for( k in 1:site_number){ 

  fem1<-subset(dat_fem, dat_fem$site == unique(dat_fem$site)[k])
  fem2<-aggregate(fem1$Count, by = list(fem1$jweek, fem1$YEAR), FUN = sum)
  colnames(fem2) = c("week", "YEAR", "Count")

  fem3<-dcast(fem2, YEAR~week, value.var = 'Count')
  fem3[is.na(fem3)] <- 0

fem_df<-df1 #here I've tried many functions but nothing has worked
# to overwrite only columns of the same name in fem_df with columns from fem3
#the same issue is occurs with the males

  assign(paste("fem_week_", unique(dat_fem$site)[k],"_table", sep = ""), fem3) #then the same process for the males  (same as female code but with male subset) 

  temp <- male_df/fem_df #this is to create the ratios, but assumes equal dimensions

  assign(paste("dat_m:f_weekly_", unique(dat_male$site)[k],"_table", sep = ""), temp) #to name data frame by site
}
```

The error is the dimensions don't always match, or the dimensions exclude/include mismatching columns, throwing off the ratio. I am unsure how to populate the df1 table correctly by overwriting its NAs with values from the male and female tables.

Comment: Can you provide simple example data and an expected output of what you're working with? Can this be boiled down to just something like `fem_df[names(fem3)] <- fem3` where the matching columns are overwritten?

Comment: This can definitely be boiled down to that. I'm unsure if a which, if, or match statement would be useful and if so, which to use.